# Can I encrypt a stream into another?

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

While logging with Serilog I managed to create a wrapper to hook into the streamed logged message so what I need now is to encrypt the logged message. This message is a stream now so can I encrypt a stream or do I have to decrypt it then encrypt it again?

Please advise on available options here?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can chain streams, see .net example of cryptostream:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream?view=netframework-4.8

Code snippet I am referring to:

```
// Create the streams used for encryption.
using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
        {

           //Write all data to the stream.
           swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
        }
         encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
    }
}
```

As you can see, most stream types use what is called the decorator pattern.

Which means you can wrap up an object into an object of the same (base) type. In this example Memory stream msEncrypt is being wrapped up in csEncrypt because it was passed as an argument in its constructor.

I think this is what you seek, you already have your source stream, wrap it up with an crypto stream :)

At least... if that is your question, after rereading it... I starting to wonder what you mean by "encrypt into"?